# In Java can Enums share a common Constructor

Tags: java, enums

I have multiple enums each share the same constructor.

```
private String name;
private String value;
private EnumName(String name, String value){
  this.name = name;
  this.value = value;
}
```

Is there a way to extend one Enum or something along those lines so I don't have to have the code in every Enum?

Comment: No `enum` constructors are implicitly `private` (even if you could extend them).

Comment: No, you cannot extends `Enum`.

Comment: http://i1.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/007/423/untitle.JPG

Comment: I think you missed my point, I didn't say it had to extend that was just the first thing that came to mind. But because of the negative reaction I think we should go ahead and delete

Comment: @Jackie There is no such possibility. If all your enums have `name` and `value` members that you need to set, each will need its own constructor.

Comment: You can use delegation. Different `enum` classes can use the same helper class maintaining the state. But as long as the state consists of the two `String` fields “name” and “value” only it’s not worth the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible - all enums extend `Enum`, so because Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance, an enum can't extend any other class.

Comment: That's not multiple inheritance: `MyEnum extends Enum`, `MyOtherEnum extends MyEnum`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: true, but it's still not possible since all enum classes extend *directly* from `java.lang.Enum` (except value-specific bodies, but those still don't help).

Comment: @JoachimSauer What does enums extending `java.lang.Enum` have to do with enums not being extendable?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: it means that you can't choose another base class (that's why I emphasized "directly").

Comment: @Joachim This situation is the same as all classes extending from `Object`. If `A extends Object` and `B extends A`, it is not multiple inheritance. Why would `Enum` be selected as base when `MyEnum` already extends `Enum` and can be selected as base?

Comment: No, it's not the same. Java does not force all classes to *directly* extend from `Object`! *`MyEnum` can not be selected as base!* That's exactly the problem. Java does not allow that.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Ok, I see it in JLS now, thanks. `The direct superclass of an enum type named E is Enum<E>`.